# Hiding a Mac application from the dock

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript

I am trying to create an application with the only purpose to implement a Applescript dictionary, and extend Applescript.
I have read of faceless applications ([agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)), but my application allows Applescript scripts to show some dialog boxes.

What can I do to avoid my application icon appears in the dock when it is invoked by Applescript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide the Dock icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620841/how-to-hide-the-dock-icon)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agent applications can show dialog boxes if they want to.

The Agent overview [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-108256) mentions this.

To set it specify `LSUIElement` as `1` in your `info.plist` file.

Comment: I checked an utility I had installed in my Mac, and I notice it uses the same trick to not show an icon in the dock. I am not sure it can be called agent, but setting that property effectively works.