# How to create a helper application (LSUIElement) that also has a (removable) dock icon

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, statusbar, mac-app-store

I've submitted a helper application (using LSUIElement)to the Mac App Store. I was under the false impression that the App Store install process would put a dock icon for helper apps.

How can I create a dock icon that the user could remove, while the status bar app runs independently (like the popular app Caffeine)? Do I need to create a non-LSUIElement app that loads the LSUIElement app, or is there a better way?

Comment: See my comment to similar SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68057340/1418981. Tested on macOS 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was misinformed by my app reviewer (two of them actually). The dock icon **is** created for you by the install process. Pressing the issue, I was able to get the app through the review process.

Comment: This now behaves differently in Lion, where no icon is created in the Dock, only in LaunchPad.

Answer (score 24):

Instead of using LSUIElement, use NSApplication's `setActivationPolicy:` method. By default, the application will have a dock icon, but by changing the activation policy to `NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory`, you get the same effect as LSUIElement while being able to change it programatically (the documentation for NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory says it is equivalent to LSUIElement=1).

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSApplication *)app {
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HideDockIcon"])
        [NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory];
}
```

Comment: Would that allow the user to remove the icon from the dock while the app is running?

Comment: Yes, you just need to call setActivationPolicy: whenever you want to change it.

Comment: -1: doc says "Currently, `NSApplicationActivationPolicyNone` and `NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory` may be changed to `NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular`, but other modifications are not supported."

Comment: Richard is correct, you can't programmatically set the policy to NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory, but you can go the other way with it: set LSUIElement to 1 in the .plist, and then (optionally) set the policy to NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular to show a dock icon.

Comment: `NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory` did not work for me but `NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited` did.

Comment: The header files say diffrently now: "In OS X 10.9, any policy may be set;" The docs still have @Richards comment.