# Hide Python Launcher icon for new QApplication()

Tags: python, macos, pyqt

I have a Threaded program that runs in the background that creates one QApplication() per thread, and everytime I got a new Python Launcher icon on my dock.

Is there a way to start a QApplication() without creating a dock icon on OSX?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think Qt supports the idea of multiple QApplication instances at all.

Answer (score 7):

There are ways to remove/disable the dock icon. See this question: ["How to hide the Dock icon"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620841/how-to-hide-the-dock-icon)

I use this Python code (after I created the `QApplication` instance):

```
def hideMacDockIcon():
    import AppKit
    # https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html
    NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular = 0
    NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory = 1
    NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited = 2
    AppKit.NSApp.setActivationPolicy_(NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited)
```

Comment: If you are not using the Python distribution bundled with Mac OS X, you need to install PyObjC, e.g. with MacPorts for Python3.2 using `sudo port install py32-pyobjc-cocoa`.

Comment: Thanks. I missed the `after QApplication` part, which turns out to matter.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is here: [Start a GUI process in Mac OS X without dock icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796028/start-a-gui-process-in-mac-os-x-without-dock-icon/9220840)

Put the following lines before instantiating QApplication:

```
import AppKit
info = AppKit.NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary()
info["LSBackgroundOnly"] = "1"
```