# Start a GUI process in Mac OS X without dock icon

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, macos

I have an application that normally runs with a standard graphical interface. However, for certain long-running tasks, it spawns additional processes of the same application that run in a "script mode," where I am controlling it from the parent process. Everything works great, except that for each child process I get another dock icon that pops in for a second or two and then disappears.

Is there a way to run an application **sometimes** without the application icon showing up on the dock? I can't edit the info.plist or anything because normally I want the dock icon. The option must be able to be set by changing a property on the process or via a command line parameter. I have full control over the source to the application. It is written in C++ (Qt), but solutions that target the native Cocoa library are fine.

If I put this code into a separate application it would cause major duplication, so I'd rather keep it the way it is. I cannot run the long-running tasks in background threads because they are doing things that must be done in a GUI thread. (In Qt, you cannot reliably use fonts, pixmaps, or render SVG content onto a QGraphicsScene on background threads.)

Any solutions?

Answer (score 10):

Motivated from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5384319/133374), you can do:

```
[NSApp setActivationPolicy: NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory];
```

or

```
[NSApp setActivationPolicy: NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited];
```

This should hide the dock icon. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for some documentation about `NSApplicationActivationPolicy`.

In Python, the code to hide the dock icon is:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/9220857/133374
import AppKit
# https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html
NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular = 0
NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory = 1
NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited = 2
AppKit.NSApp.setActivationPolicy_(NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited)
```

See also the related question ["How to hide the Dock icon"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620841/how-to-hide-the-dock-icon).

---

If you want to avoid that the dock icon pops up at all right at the beginning, you can do that:

```
import AppKit
info = AppKit.NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary()
info["LSBackgroundOnly"] = "1"
```

Comment: When I set activationpolicy to Accessory all windows are closing. How can you avoid this?

Comment: @Albert: Thx, you saved my life with these tips.

Answer (score 2):

```
import AppKit
info = AppKit.NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary()
info["LSBackgroundOnly"] = "1"
```

This code works for my Non-GUI background python script.