# Java Hide Application from Mac/Linux Dock

Tags: java, linux, macos, dock

I have read a few articles about this, however, none of them tell me how to even go about doing this. I believe that I need to incorporate some Mac file called `info.plist`.

Well, what do I do for Linux?

I do not own any Macs, nor Linuxes so I have no idea what `info.plist` is or how to get it.

Could someone please tell me:

a) How do I "add" my application to the `info.plist` **via Java**

b) How do I hide my application from the Linux dock?

info.plist Articles:

[How to hide the Dock icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620841/how-to-hide-the-dock-icon)

http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-57006.html

Comment: A link to one of the articles describing what you want would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The info.plist file would be part of your .app bundle (Application.app/Contents/Info.plist). If you are just distributing a .jar file, you aren't going to have this.

In linux, there isn't really a concept of a "Dock" in general, it would depend very much on the window manager in use at the time.