# How to remove the dock icon of a shell executable?

Tags: macos, shell, icons, executable, dock

I have a java application built with Eclipse, for Mac OS X.
This app is installed via a **.pkg** file and supposed to be **daemonized**. Everything works fine, with Macbooks **(Pro, Retina)**, but with the **iMac** I work on, when the application launches, i have an icon on the **Dock**, as you can see on the
[following link](http://res.cloudinary.com/doit0eqlo/image/upload/v1400748663/icon_uz9z6d.png).

I have already tried the solution in this topic: [**stackoverflow.com/a/620950/3641679**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/620950/3641679) but it didn't work (I still have the Dock icon). Currently the **Info.plist** looks like [this](http://res.cloudinary.com/doit0eqlo/image/upload/v1400749316/info_plist_ghrwlt.png).

What can I do?

Thank you for the time you'll be taking to help me.

#### Information (assuming the app name is testapp)

- I **stop** or **start** the daemon using **launchctl start/stop**
- When I double click on the executable (in testapp.app/Contents/MacOs/**testapp**) i have the testapp.app in the Dock (with the icon file specified in the Info.plist). Here is a screenshot **res.cloudinary.com/doit0eqlo/image/upload/v1400750376/app_k3adzh.png**
- Sorry for some links, I must have 10 reputation to post more than 2 links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I finally found the solution! The solution is in several steps.

## Step 1: Editing the Info.plist

I had to add the **LSBackgroundOnly** key. It is a **string** and has to be set to **1**.

As said in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-109268) :

> #### LSBackgroundOnly
>
> specifies whether this app runs only in the background. If this key exists and is set to “1”, Launch Services runs the app in the background only.

#### Information:

Although the documentation specifies this key is a **boolean**, setting it to a **string** with the value **1** in it does the trick.

To do so:

1. Go to your app's folder
2. Go into the **.app**'s folder then the **Contents** one (eg. /Applications/test.app/Contents)
3. Open the **Info.plist** with any text editor you want (SublimeText, TextEdit,Xcode, etc.)
4. Add the following lines before the **closing** dict tag (`</dict>`)

> > `<key>LSBackgroundOnly</key>`
> >
> > `<string>1</string>`

Save everything.

## Step 2: Edit the appname.ini

Initially I only did the part 1, so it wasn't enough. I found the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324411/unable-to-hide-dock-icon-mac-osx-for-eclipse-rcp-application).

The file is in the '**Contents/MacOs**' folder inside your application's **.app** (e.g /Applications/testapp.app/Contents/MacOs/testapp.ini).

1. Open the **.ini** file (with any text editor you want).
2. Before the `-vmargs` line, add the following line: `-nosplash`
3. After the `-vmargs` line, add the following two lines:

   > -Xdock:hidden
   >   -Dapple.awt.UIElement=false

Save the file, and now you can launch the app: it shouldn't be any icon neither in the Dock nor in the 'Force Quit' window, but your app should be running in the background.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I'm trying to do what you explained above but hI have to issues, one is overtime I edit to add: <key>LSBackgroundOnly</key><string>1</string> in info.plist and I save/close/reopen the app it says the app is damaged download again. The second thing is I don't have any ini file in contents/macOs/ I only have a script executable file with a terminal icon and nothing more.

Comment: Sorry I totally forgot about this account! Did you manage to get it done? This reminds me of some bad things lol (just as an information, I gave up java few months later)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your info.plist: -

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

Note that the value here is set to 'true' and not 1

As the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html) state: -

> Specifies whether the app is an agent app, that is, an app that should not appear in the Dock or Force Quit window. See “LSUIElement” for details.

Comment: In the plist screenshot I have provided, you can see that this option is already included in the **.plist**... Something bugs me: in the Apple doc, the LSUIElement is a String, but you have put a boolean... Which one should I put? 
And I forgot to mention it, but I tested with the boolean too...

Comment: Sorry for the double post: I've just tried with the boolean, but still, no luck. 
This is my [.plist](http://res.cloudinary.com/doit0eqlo/image/upload/v1400753348/Capture_d_%C3%A9cran_2014-05-22_%C3%A0_12_04_25_-_copie_usj7aa.png)

Comment: I originally used the integer '1', which didn't work for me, but the boolean value true does. Does your java app launch its own executable, or is it a java package that is associated with the java runtime? If the latter, I suspect this is the problem as you're targeting the jar, not the runtime.

Comment: I think the app launches its own executable, but how can I know for sure? All I know is that I have a folder in /Applications, with the **.app** folder in it, and the executable in the **.app/Contents/MacOs/** folder.
The thing that bugs me, is that this problem occurs **only** on the **iMac** I'm working on, not on my personal **Macbook Pro** or some of my friends **Macbook Pros and Retinas**. I suspect a problem relative to the computer's **family** (maybe targeting only iMacs, or something like that), but I don't know for sure...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure why that would be. I've up-voted the question, so hopefully it will get more interest.

Comment: I will try to find some other informations on the web, and post it here.
Thank you for your help and directions!